# Как правильно сделать выборку дат в pandas.DatetimeIndex?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Нужна выборка по `Date` "неделя месяца", "день недели месяца" и "неделя квартала":

```
df = pd.read_csv('1.csv')
df.columns = ['Date', 'Change%']
```

Пример данных:

```
24-Jun-19   -0.52%
21-Jun-19   1.16%
20-Jun-19   4.25%
19-Jun-19   -0.51%
```

- "Неделя месяца" это 1-я неделя всех месяцев (1), затем 2-я неделя всех месяцев (2) итд.
- "День недели месяца" - понедельники всех месяцев (1), вторнки всех месяцев (2) итд (в файле даты с пн по пт).
- "Неделя квартала" - 1-я неделя кварталов (1), 2-я неделя кварталов (2) итп.

Как сделать день недели понятно, например:

```
df['dayofweek'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Date']).dayofweek
```

или день итп. Но того, что хочется сделать в `pandas.DatetimeIndex` не вижу.

В итоге получаем строки цифрами к каждой дате.

Данные, которые [использую для анализа](https://fex.net/ru/s/9y0sbxs).

Пример:

```
Date    Change %    Неделя месяца   День недели месяца  Неделя квартала
3-Jun-19    -4.98%  1   1   6
4-Jun-19    1.13%   1   2   6
5-Jun-19    -2.16%  1   3   6
6-Jun-19    1.72%   1   4   6
7-Jun-19    2.63%   1   5   6
10-Jun-19   -1.58%  2   1   10
11-Jul-19   0.00%   2   7   10
12-Jul-19   -3.72%  2   8   10
13-Jul-19   2.23%   2   9   10
14-Jul-19   1.14%   2   10  10
```

Comment: Что-то у вас сумбур какой-то. Перечитайте и поправьте текст. По описанию вы хотите явно "неделю года", например, а называете это совершенно по-другому. Перечитайте внимательно свой текст и исправьте для начала на понятный и логичный.

Comment: Приведите ещё несколько вариантов даты и какие при этом должны получиться значения ваших колонок. В целом стало понятнее, но не до конца, нужны примеры.

Comment: Врядли вам кто-то поможет без примера того, что вы хотите получить в результате. Потому что совершенно непонятно как вы себе представляете - «первую неделю всех месяцев» записать в одной ячейке

Comment: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: А день недели месяца отличается от просто дня недели?

Comment: А в чем проблема сделать пример с 10-ю разными датами и показать на них вручную что вы хотите получить?

Comment: обращайтесь пожалуйста когда приведете в вопросе небольшой пример того, что вы хотите получить. В данной формулировке невозможно понять что хочет сделать автор вопроса... Предлагаю закрыть данный вопрос...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Реализовал то, что смог понять из комментариев, а именно `"Неделя_месяца"` и `"День_недели_месяца"` (наименования столбцов от автора вопроса).

```
df = pd.read_csv('1.csv', parse_dates=[0])
df.columns = ['Date', 'Change%']

df["Неделя_месяца"] = (df["Date"].dt.day - 1) // 7 + 1

# в январе обозначили как 1-5, в феврале 6-10, март 11-15, 15-20, 20-25 
# и тп – пн-вт-ср-чт-пт 
df["День_недели_месяца"] = (df["Date"].dt.weekday + 1) % 5 + 5*(df["Date"].dt.month-1)
```

результат:

```
In [220]: df
Out[220]:
        Date Change%  Неделя месяца  День недели месяца  Неделя квартала  Неделя_месяца  День_недели_месяца
0 2019-06-03  -4.98%              1                   1                6              1                  26
1 2019-06-04   1.13%              1                   2                6              1                  27
2 2019-06-05  -2.16%              1                   3                6              1                  28
3 2019-06-06   1.72%              1                   4                6              1                  29
4 2019-06-07   2.63%              1                   5                6              1                  25
5 2019-06-10  -1.58%              2                   1               10              2                  26
6 2019-07-11   0.00%              2                   7               10              2                  34
7 2019-07-12  -3.72%              2                   8               10              2                  30
8 2019-07-13   2.23%              2                   9               10              2                  31
9 2019-07-14   1.14%              2                  10               10              2                  32
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113807/discussion-on-answer-by-maxu----pandas-datetimeindex).

Comment: @MaxU Так как ответ принят, и думаю, всё в комментариях выяснено, то пролог к ответу желательно поправить - "Надо реализовать так ..." :)

Comment: @0xdb, немного подправил "пролог" ;)